# PHP array not filled

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I have this code :

```
$previousParam = $table['rows'][0]['groupParam'];
    $linesMiddleHeader=array();
    $lineMiddleHeader=null;
    if(array_key_exists("groupParam", $options)){
        $lineNumber+=2;
        $worksheet->setCellValue('A'.$lineNumber, $previousParam);
        $worksheet->getStyle('A'.$lineNumber)->applyFromArray($borderStyle);
    }
    foreach ($table['rows'] as $rowindex => $row) {
        $nbColumn=count($row['cells']);
        // if(array_key_exists ("groupParam", $options)){
        //     $this->getLogger()->debug(":".$row['groupParam']);
        //  }
        if($previousParam!=$row['groupParam']){
            $lineNumber+=3;
            $lineMiddleHeader=$lineNumber;
            $worksheet->setCellValue('A'.$lineMiddleHeader, $row['groupParam']);
            $worksheet->getStyle('A'.$lineNumber)->applyFromArray($borderStyle);
        }
        $linesMiddleNumber[$rowindex]=$lineMiddleHeader;
        $previousParam = $row['groupParam'];
        foreach ($row['cells'] as $column => $cell) {

            // header
            if ($rowindex == 0) {
                $title = $table['headers'][$column];
                $this->setCellValue($worksheet, $column, $previousLineNumber + 1, $title);
                $headRow = $previousLineNumber + 1;
                if(strcmp($title['title_code'], "Prix")==0){
                    $colPrice = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($column);
                }
            }
            // var_dump($linesMiddleHeader);
            if(isset($linesMiddleHeader[$rowindex]) && $rowindex == $linesMiddleHeader[$rowindex]){
                $title = $table['headers'][$column];
                $this->setCellValue($worksheet, $column, $linesMiddleHeader[$rowindex]-1, $title);
            }
            // cellule
            if ($row['level'] == 0) {
                if ($column == 0) {
                    $lineNumber++;
                }
                $columnCell=$column;
                $this->setCellValue($worksheet, $columnCell, $lineNumber + $previousLineNumber, $cell);
            }
            $worksheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is to fill `$linesMiddleHeader[]` with the different values of `$lineMiddleHeader`.

But when I look in it, the array is completely empty and I can't figure why. Maybe that's just a stupid error I did, if so it's either very well hidden or me being dumb.

Anyway, if someone is able to help me that would be awesome considering myself being nuts.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: There is no error, the array was just not filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is not $linesMiddleHeader but it is $linesMiddleNumber.

Change to this :

```
 if(isset($linesMiddleNumber[$rowindex]) && $rowindex == $linesMiddleNumber[$rowindex]){
```

Comment: Omg... I feel so ashamed... So sorry I asked for this... I need to sleep. Anyway thank you so much !

Comment: No problem..Happy coding and get some sleep :)